# Problem with sql request in selecting either single result or multiple results

Tags: mysql, sql, plsql

Good Day everyone,

Thank you for trying to help first of all. My question is about: I'm trying to write and sql request which will execute the following:

1. When user enters a certain terminal code then the sql returns the results for that terminal
2. When user enters terminal code with mask `'CN'` then the sql request returns all terminals who have `'CN'` at the beginning of that terminal

I'm aware ill probably will need to use `CASE` here.

So far i got:

```
SELECT 
    sm.terminalid as terminalcode,
    sm.sums as Latest_sums
FROM sums1 sm
... CASE
    WHEN sm.terminalid = :p_terminal 
        THEN sm.sums = (
            SELECT  max(ss.sums) from sums ss WHERE  ss.terminalid = :p_terminal
        )
    WHEN sm.terminalid = :p_terminal AND :p_terminal LIKE 'CN%' 
        THEN sm.sums = (
            SELECT sm1.sums FROM sums1 sm1 WHERE sm1.terminalid = :p_terminal
       AND :p_terminal LIKE 'CN%'
        )
    ELSE 'Incorrect Terminal ID'
  END
```

Can anyone help me where am i going wrong as the selection doesnt return multiple results when `CN` is entered.

Also if anyone got a better solution to this task please feel free to share.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT sm.terminalid as terminalcode, sm.sums as sums, 
FROM sums sm 
WHERE sm.terminalid LIKE :p_terminal || '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

To me, your logic to select records should be expressed as a condition in the `WHERE` clause, like:

```
(:p_terminal LIKE 'CN%' AND sm.terminalid like 'CN%')
OR (:p_terminal NOT LIKE 'CN%' AND sm.terminalid = :p_terminal)
```

When the given parameter looks starts with `'CN'`, this selects all records where the `terminalid` starts with `'CN'`.  Else it selects records where `terminalid` is equal to the parameter.

Query:

```
SELECT 
    sm.terminalid as terminalcode,
    sm.sums as Latest_sums
FROM sums1 sm
WHERE 
    (:p_terminal LIKE 'CN%' AND sm.terminalid like 'CN%')
    OR (:p_terminal NOT LIKE 'CN%' AND sm.terminalid = :p_terminal)
```

Comment: Makes sense, i will re-write that tonight and see what i will get thanks

Comment: @YuriyTimoshenkov: did the query work fine for you? If it did, please accept the answer by clicking the green check sign. Else, please let me know what is wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry my friend been away for 2 weeks travelling, ill test this today and let you know of the outcome

Comment: I've tried the query yes it does select multiple terminals however now when you enter a particular terminal it still selects all of them.

Comment: ill play around with it, i think the problem is in the second quatation.

Comment: Problem here that the terminal ID is still CN07 for example so when CN is just entered it displays all CN terminals however when CN07 entered the result still returns all the terminals with CN and not the particular one you are trying to select

Comment: Sorry just to clarify exactly whats happening i got a table with terminals which all have names beginning with CN, so for example CN01 , CN02, CN03 and so on. In my quire i would like either to select a specific terminal or by typing CN it will select all of them

Comment: I found a solution to the problem i believe GMB

Comment: SELECT  sm.terminalid as terminalcode,
           sm.sums as sums,
           
           
           
from sums sm
      WHERE  sm.terminalid LIKE :p_terminal || '%'